# Should I call it a pedestrian overpass or pedestrian footbridge?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

It's a bridge that allows people to cross a road. How can I call it? Can it be a pedestrian overpass or pedestrian footbridge?

[image]

Comment: Either would be fine.

Comment: I would go with "Foot Overbridge". That's the usual term used for such bridges.

Comment: @Mohit: It looks to me as if most of the 530 hits for [Foot Overbridge](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Foot+Overbridge%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are Indian usages. But [pedestrian overpass](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22pedestrian+overpass%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) gets 13,300, [pedestrian footbridge](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22pedestrian+footbridge%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) 2060, and [pedestrian bridge](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22pedestrian+bridge%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) 56,300.

Comment: @Mohit I agree with FumbleFingers. "Foot Overbridge" is not a term I have ever heard used. In fact, until you used it and I looked it up, I did not know that "overbridge" was an established word.

Comment: @KenB: Me, I'd just stick with ***footbridge***. In all relevant contexts, the only significant ***feet*** are those of pedestrians anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yep, you seem to be right. It's used commonly in India. And, as seen by the answers and comments here, doesn't seem to be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

"Pedestrian overpass", "foot bridge", and "pedestrian bridge" are all good terms. "Pedestrian footbridge" seems redundant to me. As opposed to what, an "automobile footbridge"?

I think "pedestrian bridge" is fairly common for such bridges over highways and the like. http://www.excelbridge.com/for-owners/bridge-types

"Foot bridge" is common for bridges along a trail or foot path. http://www.redwoodbridges.com/build_footbridge.html

Comment: Stretching, but "equestrian footbridge"?

Comment: Haha. +1 just for making me laugh; "automobile footbridge" ;)  At any rate, nice answer :)

Comment: @DanNeely Good point! I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

In British English it would simply be a "footbridge", even over a major road.

"Pedestrian footbridge" would be tautological.

"Pedestrian bridge" seems long-winded.

"Overbridge" is tautological - you can't have an "underbridge".

And I think only highway engineers might call it an "overpass".

Comment: Thanks a lot TrevorD! I think "footbridge" is easy for me to call it too.